# JMeter - ajax page

Tags: jmeter

I have a web page that calls another page via ajax during a page load. How can I replicate these two calls per user?

I have read various online resources around testing ajax based pages with JMeter but I'm still not clear on how to go about this.

So currently I have the following.

Thread Group:

```
- HTTP Request (Main page)
- HTTP Request (ajax call)
- Aggregate graph
```

Is this the correct approach? My assumption is each user will call the two HTTP requests, what I'm unclear about is how I can get the overall page load time for both requests.

Answer (score 0):

If there is **only one** AJAX call - your approach is correct, you might want to put both the requests under [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to see the cumulative time for the page load.

In case of **more than one AJAX calls** sequential approach won't be realistic as AJAX requests are being executed in parallel and currently JMeter doesn't provide relevant test elements to mimic this so you will need to do some scripting in order to properly simulate the AJAX calls. Check out [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article to get an idea on how this could be done and some examples.